# Fancybox 2: Updating play count

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, youtube-api, fancybox-2

I want to use fancybox 2 (or something equivalent) to embed youtube videos.  I know if the video is set to auto play the play count will not be updated.  If I disable the auto play feature in fancybox, will the play count be updated since the user is interacting with the youtube player?